# Free inventory management software needed

Tags: gratis, inventory

Anybody know any free inventory management software?

- Accounting is not required, but would be a good addition if possible.
- Must have inventory management including:

  - stock in
  - stock out
  - sales
  - purchase
  - etc.
- Platform: windows, Linux or web based.

Comment: Welcome aboard, Jacob. Your question is rather broad. As it stands, there is probably already an answer here, on one of the 41 [tag:inventory] questions (or on of the 298 "inventory control" programs at [SourceForger](https://sourceforge.net/directory/os:windows/?q=inventory+management). With some research, you could choose one of those. If you have some specific requirements, you should list them here, to help us to help you. And if you want it free, please add the [tag:gratis] tag. Good luck; I hope that you get your answer :-)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm researching the said questions and files. No luck as of now. Hope I will find one soon. I'll add the tag. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Sorry that you didn't get a reply yet. We really ***do*** want to help :-)  maybe if you can give more details? Otherwise, I hope that those hints will help.

Comment: Btw, if you find your own answer, you can post it here as an answer, and explain why chose it and then accept it as answer, which will help others in future

Answer (score 2):

I would recomend [Odoo](https://www.odoo.com/) community edition. It covers all of your requirements plus some goodies like accounting, custom modules, and a very active community. There are even solutions to create your own [SaaS](https://github.com/it-projects-llc/odoo-saas-tools) service using only the community edition

Comment: https://partkeepr.org/ and https://www.chrislands.com/ seem to be two other options, both open source